# ggplot does not react to selective inputs

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a NBA shot analysis dashboard and I created 5 variables to sort the data by that update based on their existence in the dataframes from all NBA Teams which I downloaded from [NBAsavant.com](https://www.nbasavant.com/shot_search.php). so to reproduce this on your machine you should have to just download one teams csv file.

This is done through a selectizeGroupUI and SelectiveGroupServer.

My problem is that when the user selects the restraints to subset the data, I want to pull two columns from that specific subset the user created through the inputs.

That way the final dashboard would show the x and y coordinates in the ggplot based entirely on what the users inputs are, which I am sure of how to code into the ggplot function itself.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(rsconnect)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(RCurl)
library(shinyWidgets)

# import all NBA teams csv files into one dataframe
mydir = "NBA Teams 2017-2018"
myfiles = list.files(path = mydir, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
myfiles

data_csv = ldply(myfiles, read_csv)

courtImg <- "http://robslink.com/SAS/democd54/nba_court_dimensions.jpg"
court <- rasterGrob(readJPEG(getURLContent(courtImg)),
                    width = unit(1, "npc"), height = unit(1, "npc"))

ui = pageWithSidebar(
    
    headerPanel("NBA 2017-2018 Season: Shooting Analysis"),
        
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # uiOutput("team_name"), 
            # uiOutput("name"),
            # uiOutput("shot_type"),
            # uiOutput("shot_made_flag"),
            # uiOutput("action_type")
            
            selectizeGroupUI(
                id = "my-filters",
                inline = FALSE,
                params = list(
                    team_name = list(inputId = "team_name", title = "NBA Team", placeholder = 'Select NBA Team'),
                    name = list(inputId = "name", title = "Player", placeholder = 'Select a Player'),
                    shot_type = list(inputId = "shot_type", title = "2 PT or 3 PT", placeholder = 'Select Value'),
                    shot_made_flag = list(inputId = "shot_made_flag", title = "FGA / FG", placeholder = 'Select Between All Shot Attempts or Only Shots Made'),
                    action_type = list(inputId = "action_type", title = "Shot Type", placeholder = 'Select Shot Type'))
                )
        ),
    
    mainPanel(
        #tableOutput("table"),
        plotOutput("court_plot")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    res_mod <- callModule(
        module = selectizeGroupServer,
        id = "my-filters",
        data = data_csv,
        vars = c("team_name", "name", "shot_type", "shot_made_flag", "action_type")
        )
    
    output$court_plot <- renderPlot({
        res_mod()
        ggplot(data_csv, aes(x = x, y = colory)) +
            annotation_custom(court, -250, 250, -50, 420) +
            geom_point(color = data_csv$shot_type) +
            xlim(-250, 250) +
            ylim(-50, 420)
        })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Perhaps `ggplot2(res_mod(), ...)` instead of calling it on the static object `data_csv`? (`res_mod()` is giving you a dynamic look into the frame, but I don't believe it is changing the underlying object.)

Comment: @r2evans I tried that but I get  "Error: argument "id" is missing, with no default" on my mainPanel where the ggplot should be displayed.

Comment: Add `browser()` before `res_mod()` so that you can *see* what `res_mod()` looks like to make sure it makes sense; and run this locally (not deployed to RSC or others ... inferred by the unnecessary loading of `rsconnect`). Another point: your use of `data_csv$shot_type` in the geom_point is not right; I suspect it should be `geom_point(aes(shot_type))`.

Answer (score 0):

here is corrected code:

I added `data_i = res_mod()` to my ggplot and pipelined it through the rest of code in that block.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(rsconnect)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(RCurl)
library(shinyWidgets)

# import all NBA teams csv files into one dataframe
mydir = "NBA Teams 2017-2018"
myfiles = list.files(path = mydir, pattern = "*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
myfiles

# declare csv file
data_csv = ldply(myfiles, read_csv)

# upload image of court for ggplot
courtImg <- "http://robslink.com/SAS/democd54/nba_court_dimensions.jpg"
court <- rasterGrob(readJPEG(getURLContent(courtImg)),
                    width = unit(1, "npc"), height = unit(1, "npc"))

# ui for shiny dashboard
ui = fluidPage(
  
  # change the theme to be easier on the eyes
  theme = shinytheme('darkly'),
  
    # title of shiny app
    headerPanel("NBA 2017-2018 Season: Shooting Analysis"),
        
        sidebarPanel(
            
          # create a subset of the data that changes based on user input and narrows down the choices 
            selectizeGroupUI(
                id = "my-filters",
                inline = FALSE,
                params = list(
                    team_name = list(inputId = "team_name", title = "NBA Team", placeholder = 'Select NBA Team'),
                    name = list(inputId = "name", title = "Player", placeholder = 'Select a Player'),
                    shot_type = list(inputId = "shot_type", title = "2 PT or 3 PT", placeholder = 'Select Value'),
                    shot_made_flag = list(inputId = "shot_made_flag", title = "Missed(0) or Made(1) Shot", placeholder = 'Select Between All Shot Attempts or Only Shots Made'),
                    action_type = list(inputId = "action_type", title = "Shot Type", placeholder = 'Select Shot Type'))
                ),
            status = "primary"
        ),
    
    mainPanel(
    
    # plot the court next to the user input
    plotOutput(outputId = "court_plot", width = '800px')
    )
)

# server side of the app that allows the user interactions to affect the dataframe
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
  # allow the custom subset dataframe to be called
    res_mod <- callModule(
        module = selectizeGroupServer,
        id = "my-filters",
        data = data_csv,
        vars = c("team_name", "name", "shot_type", "shot_made_flag", "action_type")
        )
    

    # the code side of the plot that plots the users input by calling the subsetted dataframe
    output$court_plot <- renderPlot({
        data_i = res_mod()
        data_i %>% ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
            annotation_custom(court, -250, 250, -50, 420) +
            geom_point(color = data_i$shot_type) +
            xlim(-250, 250) +
            ylim(-50, 420)
        })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```